# Can I POST and GET to the same PHP page

Tags: php, xml, post, get

I wanted to know if it is possible to GET and POST on the same php page, for example

I want to send data to:

```
http://www.example.com/my.php
```

So first the GET

```
http://www.example.com/my.php?task=dosomething
```

and POST some `$thexml = XML` to

```
http://www.example.com/my.php?task=dosomething
```

and then be able to access both in some code like (example)

```
// Example Code ============================

    if($_GET["task"] == "dosomething"){
      $mynewxml = $_POST["$thexml"];
    }
//==========================================
```

Comment: have you tried it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Technically no, you cannot `POST` and `GET` at the same time.  They are two different verbs, and you only get to make one during your request.

However, you will find that if you do a `POST` and include parameters in the URL, such as `yourscript.php?param1=somevalue&param2=somevalue`, then both `$_GET` and `$_POST` will be populated with their respective data.

It would be wise to read up on how HTTP actually works.  http://www.jmarshall.com/easy/http/

You should consider whether or not this is good system design on your part.  A `GET` is supposed to be for requests that don't change data on the server.  A `POST` can change data.  Even though both can be implemented to do either, it is best to follow this common practice.  You never know what some proxy or other program up the line will do with it otherwise.

Comment: @Itay Moav, ... which is why I said you "should consider" whether not this is a good idea, not that it wasn't bad outright.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can do this by including the `$_GET` parameters as part of the form action:

```
<form method='post' action='handler.php?task=dosomething'>
   ...
</form>
```

Answer (score 4):

This is how I do it....

```
if (isset($_POST['somevar'])) { 
    $somevar = $_POST['somevar']; } 
    else { 
    $somevar = $_GET['somevar']; 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can. Make sure to use `$_GET` for get and `$_POST`. There is also `$_REQUEST` which combines the two in one array. Using this is discouraged.

Comment: Explain to me how someone overwriting `POST` data with the query string creates a threat?  Someone could just as easily modify their `POST` data to begin with.  If you feel that you are more secure in using `POST` vs. `GET`, then your script is likely wide open to other problems.

Comment: @Brad, this is a big secruity threat and documented in many forums. I have added a simple example on why this is. You should always use GET when you mean get data and POST when you want post data.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I had forgotten cookies are also included. Not sure where -1 came from though :(

Comment: @bazmegakapa, my read is that it still makes no difference.  You should never be trusting data from the client, in any case.  I absolutely agree that if you are using `$_REQUEST`, you need to be aware that in the event of conflicting variables that your data will be overwritten.  However, I don't think there is anything more inherently dangerous about using `$_REQUEST` over one of the more specific global arrays.

Comment: @Brad Technically not. But suggesting beginners not to use certain techniques is sometimes inevitable. If they don't know the dangers of `$_REQUEST`, they better use the specific superglobals.

Answer (score 2):

Sure. Quite easy:

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
  ... handle form submission here ...
}

?>

<html>

<body>

<form action="thisscript.php" method="post">
... form here ...
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use both methods from the client (two different requests) and see all parameters in the same execution of your PHP script. You need to choose POST or GET.

You can use both GET and POST data coming from the same request, as others signaled.

If you need to collate data from several different request (for any reason) you need to store and manage those intermediate data yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, my young Padawan. It is as simple as changing the post attribute in a form.

```
<form method="post"....
<input type="text" name="some_name"...
```

or

```
<form method="get"....
<input type="text" name="some_name"...
```

And adding a submit button. Upon submitting, you access the HTTP Request Post/GET data stored in their respective variables.

```
$_POST['some_name'] or $_GET['some_name']
```

Comment: He wants both methods at the same time.

Comment: @bazmegakapa ah, hmmm.. there's no need for that. That actually doesn't even make sense, seeing as it's not possible to make two http requests at the same time from the same box on the same host for the same content. That flies in the face of server/client relationship.

Comment: Yes, @Brad answers the question quite well. It's *possible* in a certain way to populate both arrays. I just left comment to indicate that you're not answering the question.